# Is it just me, or is the StackExchange login page not working on Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, internet-explorer

https://stackoverflow.com/users/login

It reports a debugging error somewhere in the minimized code, fails to render properly, and the buttons are unresponsive to user input.

Comment: works on my machine™

Comment: Oh, heh.  Yes, but buggy: http://www.jcrichman.com/stack_login_glitch.png I can't speak to whether it works on machines or not, only that it doesn't work on IE11 on a Surface Pro.

Comment: It is also not working for me in IE 9

Comment: Kinda need more details on this. I just logged in using IE11 on Windows 8.1 no problem, no error. When did errors first appear? What login method did you choose? What Windows version? Do you have any addins/proxies/etc. that might be interfering? Screenshots, please?

Answer (score 10):

It is possible; your screenshot is handy, and points to a possible bug in our "stub" code that expects a particular element on *every* page (the search input named `q`), but which is not present on the revised login page; that code is only executed in some edge-case IE scenarios. So yes, this seems consistent. I've patched the code and will deploy it shortly.

Comment: That seems to have resolved the problem in both IE9 and IE11, Marc, thanks!.  The graphics in IE9 are still a bit glitchy, but the page works fine for now, as far as I can tell.