# Login page to Stack Overflow not working in IE11

Tags: bug, login, internet-explorer

Usually, I just stay logged in to Stack Overflow (via OpenID), and closing and reopening my browser (IE11) works fine to keep me logged in.

Once in a blue moon, when I open Stack Overflow, I'm not logged in anymore.  Maybe the cookie expired or something?

Anyhow, *most* of the time, I can just login and move on.  However, sometimes (like right now), I can't login at all, because the login page is not responding to user input - the "more login options" link, and the "Google", "Facebook", and "Log in" buttons do not do anything when clicked!

Closing and reopening IE doesn't resolve the problem.  Refreshing the login page does not do anything, either.  I usually have to switch browsers (I'm using FireFox to post this) in order to move on.

This is not the first time this has happened.  And it usually takes awhile (hours, days) for it to clear up so I can login using IE again.

---

Update: seems this is not the first time the login page has been buggy in IE 11:

[Is it just me, or is the StackExchange login page not working on Internet Explorer 11?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281893/)

But I'm getting a different error than JBlitzen was getting.

Using IE's Developer Tools, I see the following errors appear when clicking on the "more login options" link.

In the Console:

> SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
>   File: auth.en.js, Line: 1, Column: 927

In the Debugger:

> Access is denied.

And it has highlighted an `if(window.localStorage)` statement in `auth.en.js`.

In the Watches view, there is an Exception object displayed, and its `stack` property says the following:

> Error: Access is denied.\r\n\n
>      at auth.setPref (https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/auth.en.js?v=54a9bdad42e6:1:927)\n
>      at auth.expandExtraProviders (https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/auth.en.js?v=54a9bdad42e6:1:12314)\n
>      at Anonymous function (https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/auth.en.js?v=54a9bdad42e6:1:2339)\n
>      at n.event.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:3:12388)\n
>      at r.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:3:9090)

[image: error]

Comment: Just tested in IE11, unable to reproduce. Any messages in console?

Comment: @ChrisPickford: Yes, there is an "Access is denied" error.  I have updated my question.

Comment: Apparently if IE doesn't like the "zone" you're in, [it'll throw an exception if you try to touch localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212627/access-denied-for-localstorage-in-ie11-but-only-in-desktop-mode-not-in-metro-mo).

Comment: So, it is a bug in the login script not using a `try/catch` to handle exceptions when accessing `localStorage`? But that doesn't really explain why the login page *usually* works just fine, and only *sometimes* stops working. And I've tried several workaround (resetting the integrity settings of `AppData\LocalLow`, adding StackOverflow to the list of trusted sites), but it is still not working. It works if I put IE into InPrivate Browsing, though

Comment: Looks like the problem also affects `full-anon.en.js` when just loading the main `stackoverflow.com` page. It is also failing to access `localStorage`

Comment: After restarting the computer, the problem seems to have disappeared.